# WordPress on CentOS - SFTP and Automatic Updates

Tags: wordpress, sftp, chmod, centos6, chown

I followed the guide here to install WordPress and it works: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-on-centos-6--2. So basically, I have a WordPress website on CentOS - minimal other configuration

However, after scouring the internet for a few days now, I might be guilty of not seeing the wood through the trees. What I need is the following:

- SFTP access to the directory allowing additions/edits/deletions - how
  to add a specific user/group and allow them access just to
  /var/www/html/
- WordPress to do updates automatically - I can do the above or I can
  do this point. I can't seem to marry the two.
- To be as secure as possible - even if this means allowing WordPress
  to do SSH updates.

I can't seem to find a definitive guide on the subject, just lots of various advice on CHOWNs CHMODs etc

A **definitive guide** would, i feel, be of use to a load of people. Me included!

I have done the following but unsure how secure it is (last command run whilst in the /var/www). When I SFTP in, I still don't **JUST** see /var/www/html, I can see everything above it

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
chown -R wp-user:wp-user /var/www
usermod -a -G apache wp-user
sudo chmod -R 775 .
```

Thanks,

JJ